# KMP failure function calculation

Tags: string-matching, knuth, knuth-morris-pratt

My professor solved the kmp failure function as follows:

```
index  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
string a a b a a b a b b
ff     0 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 1
```

From other texts I checked online, I found out it might be wrong, I went back to confirm from him again and he told me he's absolutely right. Can someone pls explain to me why he thinks it's right or wrong in a simple step by step manner? Thanks

Comment: You may need to subtract one from each value in your fail table. It depends on the algorithm you are using.

Answer (score 24):

As I understand the algorithm, the failure function for your example should be the following:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a a b a a b a b b

0 1 0 1 2 3 4 0 0

f - failure function (by definition, this is the length of the longest prefix of the string which is a suffix also)

Here how I built it step by step:

f(a)         = 0   (always = 0 for one letter)

f(aa)        = 1   (one letter 'a' is both a prefix and suffix)

f(aab)       = 0   (there is no the same suffixes and prefixes: a != b, aa != ab)

f(aaba)      = 1   ('a' is the same in the beginning and the end, but if you take 2 letters, they won't be equal: aa != ba)

f(aabaa)     = 2   ( you can take 'aa' but no more: aab != baa)

f(aabaab)    = 3   ( you can take 'aab')

f(aabaaba)   = 4   ( you can take 'aaba')

f(aabaabab)  = 0   ( 'a' != 'b', 'aa' != 'ab' and so on, it can't be = 5, so as 'aabaa' != 'aabab')

f(aabaababb) = 0   ( the same situation)

Comment: This sounds more like the _Z-algorithm_ than the failure function of KMP. They are kind of similar but not exactly same.

Answer (score 1):

Since @user1041889 was confused (and got me confused too) I'll lay here the differences between the Z-function and the failure function.

Failure function, `π[i]`:

> Is the mapping of and index to the length of the longest prefix of the string which is also a suffix

But that's arguably Chinese so I'll dumb it down in order to actually understand what I'm saying:

> How big is the longest sub-string at the beginning of the string of interest, that is equal to the sub-string ending at index `i`

Or equivalently:

> What is the length of the biggest sub-string ending at index `i` which matches the start of the string of interest

So in your example:

```
index  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
string a a b a a b a b b
ff     0 1 0 1 2 3 4 0 0
```

We observe that `π[6] = 3`, so what's the substring that ends at index 6 with length 3? `aab`!

Interesting how we've seen that before!

Let's check that it is indeed the biggest one: `baab != aab`. Yup!

Notice how this implies that the failure functions always grows uniformly.

That isn't the case for the Z-algorithm.

[SAVING DRAFT to continue later]